# How is a candidate score calculated?

Tags: support, election

In https://music.stackexchange.com/election nominated candidates have a "candidate score" out of 40 listed, and a handful of specific points mentioned.

But where and how is a candidate score calculated? Can I find out what *my* score would be (without nominating myself)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253781/154443

Comment: I can't get that to work for music... it seems to only want to show me my music meta score when I try to switch to music (which is zero)

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/298418/candidate-score

Comment: Thanks @DrMayhem. I also hadn't realised user id was unique to each SE site! I think with my score of 6 I'll not nominate myself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data.StackExchange.com has some very useful tools for pulling this sort of thing.

Visit [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253781/154443) for the general way to do it for any SE site, or for a specific one for Music, I've pre-populated the site field so all you need to do is use your Music.SE profile in [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/298418/candidate-score).